# Maven inherit child dependency version

Tags: maven, dependencies, multi-module

Imagine following setup

[image: project]

I do have 2 projects (different repositories). Both are maven projects and contain a `parent/pom.xml` which holds dependency version and plugins etc.

as Project A is kinda a "standard" set of functionalities which is required by project B anyway it was kinda a hastle to always ensure I do have the same dependency versions on both projects always, so they do not clash.

1. Project A contains some Util functions, Hibernate entities, Default
   Repositories etc. (shared stuff)
2. Project B's childs are modular and do depend on those
   functionalities.

so I though I could do something with `parent` on the `pom.xml` of Project B

```
[projb-parent/pom.xml]
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>proja-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<name>Project B</name>
<artifactId>projb-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>projb-child1</module>
    <module>projb-child2</module>
</modules>
<properties>
    <!-- use the same as parent version! -->
    <foo-proja-child.version>${project.parent.version}</foo-proja-child.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>proja-child</artifactId>
        <version>${foo-proja-child.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And Project A's pom.xml basically includes a lot of dependencies, properties for specific versions, plugins etc. Which I in most cases need to define twice and also update twice.

```
[proja-parent/pom.xml]
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<name>Project A</name>
<artifactId>proja-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>proja-child</module>
</modules>
<properties>
    ...
</properties>
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

And the Project A's child:

```
[proja-parent/proja-child/pom.xml]
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>proja-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>proja-child</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Project A Child</name>
<properties>
    <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And I want to have all `plugins/dependencies/dependencyManagement/pluginManagement` version and configurations defined in the `proja-parent/pom.xml` to be inherited to `projb-parent/pom.xml`

HINTs:

- Versions are updated with: `mvn versions:set -DgroupId=foo.* -DartifactId=* -DnewVersion=1.2.3 versions:commit`
- `mvn clean deploy` is used to deploy on artifactory
- I checked the versions set in the uploaded pom files on the repo and they are correctly set to `1.2.3` for each of `proja-parent/pom.xml` and `proja-parent/proja-child/pom.xml`
- Childs are packaging=jar
- Parents are packaging=pom
- I tried friendly versions and flatten, but how would you pass down the "version" onto the Project B
- somehow it's downloading the `proja-parent` dependency version correctly but the build is failing because it tries to download 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT from the repository afterwards when any child of Project B is build (mvn dependency:list-repositories).

`mvn dependency:list-repositories` output:

```
...
1744 [INFO] Building projb-parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                              [1/60]
...
Downloading from my-server-repo: https:/someserver.com/artifactory/group/foo/proja-child/1.2.3/proja-child-1.2.3.pom
...
7584 [INFO] Building projb-child 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT                               [2/60]
7584 [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from my-server-repo: https:/someserver.com/artifactory/group/foo/proja-child/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
7680 [WARNING] The POM for foo:proja-child:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

The effective pom (shown by Intellij) also give me the correct version as dependency version for the `proja-child`:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>proja-child</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
     ...
```

## TLDR;

So why is MAVEN trying to access 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT of the repository. It fails obviously because there is no 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on the repository.

### UPDATE 1

Instead of using `<foo-proja-child.version>${project.parent.version}</foo-proja-child.version>` I hardcoded the value, which actually changed it from 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 1.2.3 for `projb-child1(2)`. But It still tries to resolve 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Tldr, ..i would *not*: inherit my "root pom" from "spring-boot-parent"! (That's not how they show it in ["gs-spring-boot-modular"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)..)

Comment: ..but that probably few affects you issue...the answer to this must be in: effective pom+ modular(/opened) projects, and what IntelliJ/shell do with it.

Comment: Please check effective pom of: child-a dependent project(s), not only the "managed version", but the really resolved one.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Intellij. Because it is not running on gitlab cicd with maven:3.8.6-openjdk-18-slim docker image

Comment: @xerx593 on the provided link it is actually exactly the same, lol. It's just not that you have another layer to manage the project specific dependencies

Comment: "projb-child1/pom.xml" seems to have 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT as version for the "proja-child" dependency?! Is ${project.parent.version} resolving to 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in case of a "projb-child1" because it's "projb-parent" has this version?